# How do I mirror multi-planar reconstruction images

Tags: c++, vtk

I tried many methods, but they didn't work. For example, operating the camera (can work for a short time, but it will reset when the mouse moves to the slice line), setting the vtktransform for vtkimagereslice (can work, but after moving the slice line, the slice center changes,i set a mirror vtktransform  mattrax), and setting the rotation for vtkimageactor (completely invalid), all of which didn't work,

I hope the slice image can be flipped along its x-axis

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by setting the resliceimage transform. I set the wrong image boundary before. I don't know how to close the problem, so I added this answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).